# When i Try to reverse the Axis with the following code i do not obtain the reverse orientation

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

When I try to reverse the axis with the following code I do not obtain the reverse orientation

```
$chart1->getChartAxisX()->setAxisOrientation(Axis::ORIENTATION_REVERSED);
```

How to change the coordinate axis from small to large?

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Please see; [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Make sure you provide an [mre]. To show your images, put an exclamation mark (`!`) before the URI (see [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74861289/revisions) for an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want the data sources to appear in the table in the same order as the bar chart, and your graph is a horizontal bar, so your code is fine, and it does invert the X-axis.
But why doesn't it work, and so I looked at the source code. The code for `getChartAxisX()` in your method looks like this

```
    public function getChartAxisX()
    {
        if ($this->xAxis !== null) {
            return $this->xAxis;
        }

        return new Axis();
    }
```

As you can see, when the member variable xAxis does not exist, this method creates a new object and returns it.  But this new object is not set into the $chart object, so your set method does not work on the $chart object.

However, I have found that Chart does not have a setXAxis() method in PhpSpreadsheet, so if you want it to work, you should set the Axis object in when you create the $chart object.

```
$axisX = new Axis();
$axisX->setAxisOrientation(Axis::ORIENTATION_REVERSED);
$chart = new Chart(
    "chart", // name
    $title, // title
    $legend, // legend
    $plotArea, // plotArea
    true, // plotVisibleOnly
    DataSeries::EMPTY_AS_GAP, // displayBlanksAs null,
    $xAxisLabel, // xAxisLabel - Owen added null xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel, // yAxisLabel
    $axisX //xAxis
);
```

Now it should do what you want.